# Individual Google Sheet Cell Value to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-api

I'm trying to pull data from individual cells in a google sheet to a webpage. So far I have something like this:

```js
    function loadPrice() {
  var url="mygooglesheetslink";
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
  
  
}
```

```html
    <body onload="loadPrice()">
    <div id="price"></div>
  </body>
```

It pulls everything from the sheet into the page, and I'm just trying to figure out how I can individually place cell values from the sheet in particular places on the page.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use the `google.script run.withSuccessHandler().somegasfunction` documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication). It's very easy to use.  And you can call any google apps script in your project.

Answer (score 0):

This updates select options from a spreadsheet.

Google App Script:

```
function getSelectOptions()
{
  sortOptions();
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Options');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var options=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    options.push(vA[i][0]);
  }
  return vA;
}
```

Javascript:

```
  $(function() {
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateSelect)
          .getSelectOptions();
      });

function updateSelect(vA)
{
  var select = document.getElementById("sel1");
  select.options.length = 0; 
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
  }
}
```